# Event Handler in WPF

Tags: wpf, event-handling

Why are all event handlers in WPF declared with private access by default?

```
private void CommonClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Is it a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are not supposed to be used by other  classes, so this is default behaviour.

BTW: Use commands in stead and System.Windows.Interactivity, a framework such as galasoft and follow the MVVM pattern.

```
<UserControl.....>
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:YourViewModel/> <!-- Use a viewmodel locator instead -->
</UserControl.DataContext>
    <Button Content="Click Me" Command={Binding SomeCommand}/>
</UserControl>
```

VM:

```
public class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
   public ICommand SomeCommand{get; set;}

   public YourViewModel()
   {
       InitStuff();
   }

   protected virtual void InitStuff()
   {
      SomeCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonClicked);
   }

   private void ButtonClicked() 
   {
     // DO stuff 
   }
}
```